# PayPal with IPN enabled invoking error on cmd = "_cart"

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am using PayPal Website Payment Standard with IPN enabled.

Before I was setting **cmd** variable like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
```

but then I canged it to

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
```

Also I changed some other variables inside my form

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item1">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item2">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="121">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="122">
```

But when the form is Posted to PayPal I am getting this error.

[image: Pay Pal Error "We have detected a problem with the shopping cart.If the problem persists,please contact the merchant."]

**Thanks in Advance...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you add `target="paypal"` in the form opening tag?

could you show the entire form?

Comment: you still have to create a 'view cart' button for your site, did you do that?

Comment: follow each step carrefully -> https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_to_cart_outside

Comment: Thanks mighty I really Appreciate your comments.Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have to include the upload variable to identify the form as a cart:

```
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
```